# how can i make a filter to exclude repeated data on a data frame in R system?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

i have a data frame like this:

```
question <- data.frame("cars"=c(1,1,2,2,34),"bike"=c(1,1,2,2,37),"motorcycle"=c(3,3,2,2,45),
                   "trycicle"=c(3,3,4,4,56),"skate"=c(1,1,4,4,78))
```

and i want to make a filter to delete the repeated data and maintain the different numberns, is this possible in R system?

the new data frame has to be like this:

```
question2 <- data.frame("cars"=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,34),"bike"=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,37),"motorcycle"=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,45),
                   "trycicle"=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,56),"skate"=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,78))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `duplicated` to turn the repeated values to `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

question %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = 
         ~replace(., duplicated(.) | duplicated(., fromLast = TRUE), NA)))

#  cars bike motorcycle trycicle skate
#1   NA   NA         NA       NA    NA
#2   NA   NA         NA       NA    NA
#3   NA   NA         NA       NA    NA
#4   NA   NA         NA       NA    NA
#5   34   37         45       56    78
```

In base R you may use `lapply` -

```
question[] <- lapply(question, function(x) 
                replace(x, duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE), NA))
```